# How to filter image types in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php

I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser and I want to return all image types BUT .gif Anyone know how to do this? (Yes, I've read the docs and can't figure this out)

Code so far...

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
```

Is there some way such as this:

```
foreach($html->find('img[!=.gif]') as $element)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use simplehtmldom. With built in Dom and xpath you can do this: img[not(contains(@src,'gif'))]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the src of each item ends with `.gif`:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
  if (strtolower(substr($element->src, -4)) == '.gif')
    continue;

  // code here
}
```

Comment: Probably should `strtolower` your `substr` call.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you will do:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    if ( !endsWith ( '.gif' , strtolower ( $element->src ) ) ) {
        /* code */
    }
}

function endsWith( $str, $sub ) {
    return ( substr( $str, strlen( $str ) - strlen( $sub ) ) === $sub );
}
```

Although, this selector: `[attribute$=value]` matches elements that have the specified attribute and it ends with a certain value.  So you could remove all gifs and then foreach all images.